# How to get the path in build.gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy, build

I am working on build.gradle in a project directory. i want to know how can I get the path of the directory with one folder back in gradle task

```
task myTask << {
println file('.')
println projectDir}
```

This would return me the path which say is `c:\a\b\c` which is current directory

but i want to go to the path `c:\a\b`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
task currentDir << {
    println file('.')
    println projectDir
}

task previousDir << {
    println file('..')
    println file("$projectDir/..")
}
```

Comment: it works, but i gives me the path of the current directory, but i want the path one folder back, as there is another file there which i have to run through current task

Comment: @Sidharth , I've just tested this on windows, works just fine. I edited my answer to make this more clear. Please note the difference, you did use single dot and that's current directory. For a directory one above it you can use '..' (two dots).

That's nothing unusual. When you are in console, you can use 'cd ..' to go one dir up.